# cryptic LDA plotting error

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm trying to get a few plots of an LDA classifier I trained on some data, but I'm getting a strange error:

```
> plot(CSP.reduced.LDA)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  duplicated name 'CSP.1' in data frame using '.'
```

I'm not sure what would be a minimal working example for this, but I can give a summary of what the data is like:

```
> summary(CSP.by.trial[[subject.ind]])
     CSP.1           CSP.2           CSP.3            CSP.4       targets
 Min.   :1.206   Min.   :1.780   Min.   :0.0864   Min.   :2.714   0:140  
 1st Qu.:1.407   1st Qu.:3.398   1st Qu.:0.2300   1st Qu.:3.205   1:140  
 Median :1.470   Median :3.784   Median :0.3044   Median :3.428          
 Mean   :1.477   Mean   :3.804   Mean   :0.3247   Mean   :3.500          
 3rd Qu.:1.546   3rd Qu.:4.218   3rd Qu.:0.3986   3rd Qu.:3.723          
 Max.   :1.762   Max.   :5.454   Max.   :0.9466   Max.   :5.142


> CSP.reduced.LDA$terms
CSP.by.trial$targets ~ CSP.1 + CSP.2 + CSP.3 + CSP.4
attr(,"variables")
list(CSP.by.trial$targets, CSP.1, CSP.2, CSP.3, CSP.4)
attr(,"factors")
                     CSP.1 CSP.2 CSP.3 CSP.4
CSP.by.trial$targets     0     0     0     0
CSP.1                    1     0     0     0
CSP.2                    0     1     0     0
CSP.3                    0     0     1     0
CSP.4                    0     0     0     1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "CSP.1" "CSP.2" "CSP.3" "CSP.4"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(CSP.by.trial$targets, CSP.1, CSP.2, CSP.3, CSP.4)
attr(,"dataClasses")
CSP.by.trial$targets                CSP.1                CSP.2 
            "factor"            "numeric"            "numeric" 
               CSP.3                CSP.4 
           "numeric"            "numeric"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, I've got it. It looks like `plot.lda()` from the MASS package chokes on `.`s in column names. Replacing them with a space character fixed it. No idea why it doesn't break `lda()` to begin with, though.

Comment: Meanwhile, using a space separator breaks the stepwise LDA from package `klaR`...

Comment: You don't want a space in column names. Such names are not syntactically valid and often need special treatment. If `plot.lda()` really doesn't like `.` (I would consider that a bug), try using `_` or nothing.

Comment: I figured as much, so I dropped spaces. Seems strange that `paste` would default to `sep=" "` though, in light of all this (I use it to name columns with sequences).